# Remoção de Símbolos em colunas do dataframe em Python

Tags: dataframe, replace

Feito um web scraping em  Python , até aí ok, só que gerou uma tabela com ( ) e [ ], \n, -, queria um código função em python para  usar para limpar o  dataframe da figura abaixo, pode ser coluna a coluna. , só permanecendo os nomes.
Obrigado!

Tentei:

```
#dataFrame.replace(to_replace='[' , value = "") 
#DataFrame.replace (to_replace = None, value = None, inplace = False, limit = None, regex = False, method = 'pad')
```

&

```
def remove_str(txt):
    list_remove = [' [',' ]',' \n',' -',' ]
    for t in list_remove:
        txt = txt.strip(t)
    return txt
tempdata = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time','Value'])
data['titulo'] = data.apply(lambda row : remove_str(row['titulo']), axis=1)
```

[image: tabelas (dataframes) os filmes, organizando-os por por gênero e por ano.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Frame de teste

```
import pandas as pd
import re

titulo = ['[Cobra Kai]', '[Bridgerton]', '[Vikings]']
genero = ['[\nAction, Comedy, Drama]', '[\nDrama, Romance]','[\nAction,Adventure, Drama]']
ano = ['[(2018)]','[(2020)]','[(2013-2020)]']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Titulo': titulo, 'Genero': genero, 'Ano':ano})
```

Código

```
simbolos = '][\n)( '
pattern = "[" + simbolos + "]"

df = df.applymap((lambda x: re.sub(pattern, '', x)))
```

1. Criando o data frame de teste
2. definindo os símbolos que serão excluídos
3. Definindo um padrão
4. Aplicando a função re.sub em todo o data frame

Saída

```
      Titulo                 Genero           Ano
0   CobraKai    Action,Comedy,Drama          2018
1   Bridgerton  Drama,Romance                2020
2   Vikings     Action,Adventure,Drama  2013-2020
```

Comment: Muito bom , este código funciona nesta nova tabela! Porém quando uso no meu DataFrame, não funciona. Pode aplicar este código, mas ao invés de criar um novo, para o já existente definido como dataframe (tudo minúsculo)                                                                                              
criar simbolos = '][\n)( ' 
pattern Código = "[" + simbolos + "]"

df = df.applymap((lambda x: re.sub(pattern, '', x)))

Comment: Muito bom , este código funciona nesta nova tabela! Porém quando uso no meu DataFrame, não funciona. Pode aplicar este código, mas ao invés de criar um novo, para o já existente definido como dataframe (tudo minúsculo)                                                                                              
Data Frame
Ou seja usar dataframe ao invés de uma nova tabela abaixo:  
titulo = ['[Cobra Kai]', '[Bridgerton]', '[Vikings]']
genero = ['[\nAction, Comedy, Drama]', '[\nDrama, Romance]','[\nAction,Adventure, Drama]']
ano = ['[(2018)]','[(2020)]','[(2013-2020)]']

Comment: @MDataScience, boa tarde! Eu não entendi muito bem a colocação. Ele funciona pra você ou não funcionou? Caso não tenha funcionado, poste na pergunta o seus dados reais, dessa forma poderei testar e te ajudar de uma maneira mais adequada. Abraço!

Comment: O seu código funciona, mas no meu código não funcionou, então nao funcionou no meu caso , na tabela existente. Sim o ideal seria testar no código direto , pois tenho tentando fazer de várias formas e entender por que esta dando erro.. Sou novo por aqui , posso colocar o código lá (é para estudo mesmo) só que fica sem formatação.

Comment: @MDataScience, bom dia! Coloque seus dados em alguma hospedagem na nuvem e disponibilize o link na pergunta, dessa forma posso analisar melhor o que está havendo. Abraço!